# Permission Denial: getIntentSender(): uid=1001, (need uid=1000)

Tags: android, security

I'm making an app controlling Phone network state (switch between 2G/3G).

For some reason my app uses sharedUserId="android.uid.system", but run under context of Phone, (i.e. android:process="com.android.phone")
Everything worked fine til i've started to use AlarmManager.

Inside my service's onCreate() (which runs in context of process com.android.phone of course), following function gives exception:

```
pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class), 0);
```

i'm getting this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(21289): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: getIntentSender() from pid=21289, uid=1001, (need uid=1000) is not allowed to send as package com.net_toggle
```

AlarmReceiver is a private class of my service which has the same context.

I've search in internet and this site of course, but cannot find solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Helping link regarding this question**

https://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/using-com-android-internal-part-1-introduction/

**Edit** :

did you added the `<receiver>` to your manifest ?

like :

```
      <receiver android:name="MyScheduleReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="MyStartServiceReceiver" >
    </receiver>
```

and also permission :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

Comment: ok good, please than  share your code which may help some other peoples  !

Comment: I doubt problem is in BOOT_COMPLETED intent reception. Because issue is in non-consistent UID, but i've solved it by different way. I've hacked ADT to get access to all hidden and internal Android SDK functions. Now i don't need to use reflection to get Phone object, instead i use functions and objects directly. Since,  i don't need android.uid.system shared UID anymore, i've changed it to android.uid.phone and my application now has the same UID everywhere and works fine with AlarmManager.

Comment: This is the guide how to add hidden/internal Android SDK to Eclipse: https://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/using-com-android-internal-part-1-introduction/

Comment: Is it common way to accept my own answer as someone's? It looks weird for me.

Comment: @Saar I have encountered a same problem when instrumented testing the PendingIntent.getBroadcast, when the output message is `ava.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: getIntentSender() from pid=3790, uid=10085, (need uid=10058) is not allowed to send as package org.company.full.test` . But how does this error link to hidden SDK? and How should I fix it in the context of instrumented testing?